# how to install visual studio libraries in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, rasa-nlu, rasa

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Hp\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h_n6a0vq\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h_n6a0vq\\ujson\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k0pxj3be\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Hp\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\Include\ujson'
     cwd: C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h_n6a0vq\ujson\
Complete output (5 lines):
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'ujson' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Hp\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h_n6a0vq\ujson\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h_n6a0vq\ujson\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k0pxj3be\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Hp\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\Include\ujson' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: So what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install C++ build tools from here:  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ These are required to build certain python wheels. They are not themselves python packages, so it's not something you do in anaconda.

Comment: Why should you not do it in anaconda? Anaconda is language agnostic and ships with a lot of non-python packages. For example the compilers package

Answer (score 0):

You can install vs build tools ( visual studio libraries required by python on Windows) via:

```
conda install anaconda::vs2015_runtime
```

Reference:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/vs2015_runtime

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).